# How to find the sum of all entries of a certain matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two matrices $A=\pmatrix{19 & 17\\\ 1& 4}$ and $B=\pmatrix{\sqrt{3} & -1\\\ 1& \sqrt{3}}$. I want to find the sum of all entries of $(ABA^{-1})^{300}$. Where to attack?

I found a good pattern for $B^{2n}$ and can see that $(ABA^{-1})^{300}=AB^{300}A^{-1}$ but it seems not the right way necessarily. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: $$\frac12B=\pmatrix{\sqrt3/2&-1/2\\1/2&\sqrt3/2}$$ is a rotation matrix. I'm sure that identifying the angle of rotation will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to note that the sum of all elements of $C$ is
$$\pmatrix{1&1}C\pmatrix{1\\1}.$$
Then
$$\pmatrix{1&1}AB^{300}A^{-1}\pmatrix{1\\1}
=\pmatrix{20&21}B^{300}\pmatrix{-13/59\\18/59}
$$
etc.

Comment: Thanks Lord for the good points.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Note that $$B^2=2\begin{pmatrix}1&-\sqrt3\\\sqrt3&1\end{pmatrix}\\B^4=(B^2)^2=4\begin{pmatrix}1&\sqrt3\\-\sqrt3&1\end{pmatrix}\\B^8=(B^4)^2=16\begin{pmatrix}1&-\sqrt3\\\sqrt3&1\end{pmatrix}=8B^2\\B^{300}=(B^8)^{37}\cdot B^4=-B^{41}=-(B^8)^5\cdot B=\cdots$$ Multiplying the final three matrices together shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: As $\det B=4$, then I fear you've lost some powers of $2$ along the way.

Comment: So you suggest me to evaluate $B^{300}$ as you did first and then myltiply $AB^{300}A^{-1}$  and then make a summation of the final result?

Comment: @B.B. Yes, adding the values of 2x2 matrices isn't at all tedious.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown This okay now?

Comment: Thanks both of you.

Answer (score -1):

Note that $$(ABA^{-1})^n = \underbrace{(AB\overbrace{\color{red}{A^{-1}})(\color{red}{A}}^{\text{identity}}B\color{red}{A^{-1}})(\color{red}{A}BA^{-1})\cdots (ABA^{-1})}_{n\text{ times}}$$ so clearly, for any invertible matrix $A$ we have $$(ABA^{-1})^{300} = AB^{300}A^{-1}$$ with the pattern on $B$ the problem is solved.

Comment: You've written $A^{-1}BA$ not $ABA^{-1}$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire thank you very much, silly error

Comment: Btw did you get my invite to the chatrooms?

Comment: Yes! I got it! But I've forgot to join ahah I'll do it now, thanks for the reminder